# pino logger поменять местами порядок вывода

Tags: javascript, логирование

Как в JS pino logger поменять местами level и timestamp?
В документаци есть formatters log(https://github.com/pinojs/pino/blob/master/docs/api.md#log), но я так и не понял, что он делает, что с ним не пробовал, он либо ничего не меняет, либо добавляет в конец перед message 
Выводит так:

```
{"level":"...", timestamp:"...",  ..., "message":...}
```

Нужно так:

```
{timestamp:"...", "level":"...", ..., "message":...}
```

Comment: зачем это вообще надо?

Comment: @DmitriiSedov нужен именно такой формат